# Hostgator displaying all my html files instead of index

Tags: html, dns, hosting, web-hosting, website-hosting

I was hoping you can help with this, i only have about a week ( 10-15h) of experience with front end web development. but i cant figure this out. im trying to find the answer online but cannot locate it.

I purchased my domain name with google, uploaded my html files as well as img files to hostgator. when i go to my site, instead of it going to my index html file it displays all of them. [take a look at what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fxJX.png)

how do i solve this ? or if you know a link to some reading materials kindly provide it so i can learn :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put all your public pages in the `public_html` folder. It's the main entry point or the root of your domain name. Also, rename the `Index.html` file to `index.html`.

Comment: thank you for the tip, i just looked in my cpanel, the files are located in the  public_html folder, along with my img folder, and a folder i did not add called cgi-bin

Comment: Can you try renaming Index.html to index.html?

Comment: that worked, who know a capital would cause an issue like that, thank you for the help, it's very appreciated!